# following code I have made an SOR iteration in python

Tags: python

In the following code I have made an SOR iteration in python. I seem to be getting the wrong output. It seems to be just outputting the b array when it should be solving the system. Is there something wrong with my function or call of my function? Here is the code below! I don't think my values of x should be all 1's and I don't think it should just take one iteration! When I run this code for smaller x, b, xo it works! but I am trying to run it for x which is a 10x10, b which is a 10x1 and xo which is a 10x1

```
import numpy as np 
import math 

x = np.array([[3.0, 1.0, 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],[1.0, 3.0, 1.0, 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.], [0., 1.0, 3.0, 1.0, 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.], [0., 0, 1.0, 3.0, 1.0, 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.], [0., 0., 0., 1.0, 3.0, 1.0, 0., 0., 0., 0.], [0., 0., 0., 0., 1.0, 3.0, 1.0, 0., 0., 0.], [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.0, 3.0, 1.0, 0., 0.], [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.0, 3.0, 1.0, 0.], [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.0, 3.0, 1.0], [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.0, 3.0]])
b = np.array([1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0])
x0 = np.array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.])
tol =  10 ** (-15)
max_iter = 20
w = 1.5

def SOR(A, b, x0, tol, max_iter, w): 
    if (w<=1 or w>2): 
        print('w should be inside [1, 2)'); 
        step = -1; 
        x = float('nan') 
        return 
    n = b.shape 
    x = x0 

    for step in range (1, max_iter): 
        for i in range(n[0]): 
            new_values_sum = np.dot(A[i, 1 : (i - 1)], x[1 : (i - 1)]) 
            for j in range(i + 1, n[0]): 
                old_values_sum = np.dot(A[i, j], x0[j]) 
            x[i] = b[i] - (old_values_sum + new_values_sum) / A[i, i] 
            x[i] = np.dot(x[i], w) + np.dot(x0[i], (1 - w))  

        if (np.linalg.norm(x - x0) < tol): 
            print(step) 
            break 

       x0 = x 


    print("X = {}".format(x)) 
    print("The number of iterations is: {}".format(step)) 
SOR(x, b, x0, tol, max_iter, w)
```

Which gives the following output, which is not what I am looking for

```
1
X = [1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
The number of iterations is: 1
```

Comment: The lines that set `step` and `x` in the `if w` are pointless, since you then immediately return. I would also for sanity not 'rename' `x` to `A` and then create a local variable called `x` inside the function. Not sure if this is relevant to the problem you are having however.

Comment: so then what would I have to change to follow your advice?

Comment: when I run this code for smaller x, b and xo it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were errors in the indices of new_values_sum and old_values_sum. For old_values_sum, the for loop doesn't make sense as it just discard old values.

In the line after that there is a bracket error.

For termination condition , I don't think checking the norm between x and x0 suffices.

I have included some codes to check the validity of the solution.

```
import numpy as np 
import math 

A = np.array([[3.0, 1.0, 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],[1.0, 3.0, 1.0, 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.], [0., 1.0, 3.0, 1.0, 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.], [0., 0, 1.0, 3.0, 1.0, 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.], [0., 0., 0., 1.0, 3.0, 1.0, 0., 0., 0., 0.], [0., 0., 0., 0., 1.0, 3.0, 1.0, 0., 0., 0.], [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.0, 3.0, 1.0, 0., 0.], [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.0, 3.0, 1.0, 0.], [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.0, 3.0, 1.0], [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.0, 3.0]])
b = np.array([1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0])
x0 = np.array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.])
tol =  10 ** (-15)
max_iter = 20
w = 1.5

def SOR(A, b, x0, tol, max_iter, w): 
    if (w<=1 or w>2): 
        print('w should be inside [1, 2)'); 
        step = -1; 
        x = float('nan') 
        return 
    n = b.shape 
    x = x0 

    for step in range (1, max_iter): 
        for i in range(n[0]): 
            new_values_sum = np.dot(A[i, :i], x[:i])
            old_values_sum = np.dot(A[i, i+1 :], x0[ i+1: ]) 
            x[i] = (b[i] - (old_values_sum + new_values_sum)) / A[i, i] 
            x[i] = np.dot(x[i], w) + np.dot(x0[i], (1 - w))  
        #if (np.linalg.norm(x - x0) < tol): 
        if (np.linalg.norm(np.dot(A, x)-b ) < tol):
            print(step) 
            break 
        x0 = x

    print("X = {}".format(x)) 
    print("The number of iterations is: {}".format(step))
    return x
x = SOR(A, b, x0, tol, max_iter, w)
print(np.dot(A, x))
```

The code produces:

```
X = [ 0.27638192  0.17085425  0.21105529  0.19597989  0.20100503  0.20100502
  0.1959799   0.21105527  0.17085427  0.27638191]
The number of iterations is: 19
[ 1.00000002  0.99999998  1.00000002  0.99999999  1.00000001  1.          1.
  1.          1.          1.        ]
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution! To further visualize what is happening in my code how could I plot the number of iterations it takes to achieve that iteration error of less then 10^{-15}as a function of the SOR extrapolation parameter w where $w\in [1,2), using omega=nimpy.linspace(1,1.99,100) to cover the interval [1,1.99] with 100 spaces.

Comment: could you edit that plot in? I have accepted your answer, thanks I see where I went wrong!

Comment: rather than returning the x, return the number of iteration instead. then write a for loop to record those values and plot it.

Comment: you should always try it first and report back if you really encounter difficulty. you learn more that way.

Comment: honestly I am not quite sure how to do it! I have gotten this far but not sure how to plot it!

Comment: if you could help me out that would be great, if not thanks for helping me fix my mistakes!

Comment: where is the difficulty, getting the values or plotting?

Comment: not sure how to do what you have listed above, return the iteration number and writing a loop to record the value and plot it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182370/discussion-between-siong-thye-goh-and-fr14).

Comment: Sorry I know this is old but I am trying to run this code. I get the following error: ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence. Do you know why?